# Android studio problems with gradle new installation

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I had some problems with android studio. It fails at compiling time just with some projects (others works fine with same code) because gradle 1.6

I tried something I found on stackoverflow and it started to fail always so I decided to remove android studio folder and download it again.

Now I imported my projects to this new installation and it tells me that my folders are not in gradle and delete them (the folders). SO I cannot do anything.

What do I have to do for deleting all files related to android studio. Grades, plugins... everything. I want to make a clean installation for trying to get everything working without problems.

Should I try IntelliJ Idea instead? What do I have to install for that? Just if it is better than android studio.

Comment: You can locate and delete all the `AndroidStudio` folders, they are stored in the [same place](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) as other IntelliJ IDEA based products, just the name is different.

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` and exact output of the gradle